# How to send data from SIM800 series to a REST API in Java

Tags: at-command, jssc, java-communication-api

I am working on a project where I have to create an API which would receive data sent from sim cards over http. 
For this purpose I am trying to implement a program which can emulate the process so that I can execute AT commands from my java program and eventually make an HTTP Post or Get to a REST API. For this purpose I would be using my cell-phone which I have connected to my laptop using USB or bluetooth.

I am very new to this area of programming. Can you please help me regarding this?

Myself, I tried using Java Communications (but that doesn't work on 64 bit windows), HyperTerminal and ATCommand tester.

Answer (score 0):

For serial port api in java consider using serialpundit, jssc or fazecast libraries (all are on github). For null modem emulation consider tty2tty/tty2comKm (linux) or com0com (windows) drivers.